# I have to use AND OR in same condition in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to use AND OR in the same condition of a stage.

`and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.UseCase }}', 'UseCase3'), or(eq(${{ parameters.NewCluster }}, true)))`

I am getting the below error for applying this condition in the pipeline

`An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unexpected symbol: ')'. Located at position 54 within expression: and(succeeded(), ne('UseCase3', 'UseCase3'), or(eq(False, true))). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996`

Comment: Count the parentheses.

Comment: Try to remove the last `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your last `or` needs at least 2 variables to work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#or)

Comment: Thanks, It works now, I missed the documentation part of this conditions